# Read hidden zip file

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a jpeg, and on the end of it I wrote a zip file.

Inside this zip file is a single txt file called `hidden.txt`. I can change the extension to zip and read the file just fine on my laptop (debian) but when I try to read it using either a `ZipInputStream` or using `ZipFile` I get an error telling me it's not a zip file.

I tried separating the jpg part out first by reading the whole thing to a `Bitmap` then writing that to a `byte[]`, however the `byte[]` encompassed more than just the image.

My method to combine the bitmap and the zipFile (a `byte[]`)

```
private byte[] combineFiles(Bitmap drawn, byte[] zip) throws
        IOException {
    InputStream in;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    /*write the first file*/
    byte[] img;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    drawn.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    img = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(img);
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    in.close();

    /*add the second (hidden) file*/
    in = new ByteArrayInputStream(zip);

    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    out.flush();
    in.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

So really I have two questions,

1. How do I separate the jpg and zip portions of the file?
2. How do I unzip `hidden.txt` (preferably into a `byte[]`)

   - fairly certain I know this one, but what I am doing currently does not work, probably because I am doing #1 wrong

Comment: maybe just put a password on the zip file?

Comment: @satnam not really what I want to do, defeats the purpose

Comment: how about finding where the zip starts by searching the byte[] array of the combined file for the "PK" magic number of the zip file. then separate the two streams and use ZipInputStream for the zip part of the bytes.

Comment: @faljbour I tried that, however I think I was doing it wrong as it kept failing to find it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'reading the whole thing to a `Bitmap`'? I would expect any method that reads an input stream and produced a `Bitmap` to stop reading at the end of the image, so the rest of the stream is the .zip data.

Comment: @EJP i am reading it using bitmapfactory, and I would assume so as well, however that is apparently not the case.

Comment: You could try reading it with `javax.image.ImageIO,` but you might get the same problem.

Comment: @EJP Android does not have `javax.image.ImageIO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well here's how I would do this. Although it's very hacky.

The problem is that it's hard to tell the index of the boundary between the image data and the zip data.  Assuming that you can write arbitrary data after the image data and still have a working image file, here is something you could try:

1. write out the image data.
2. write out a magical string like "BEGIN_ZIP"
3. write out the zip data.

Now, when you are trying to read things back in:

```
byte[] data = readAllTheBytes();
int index = searchFor("BEGIN_ZIP", data) + "BEGIN_ZIP".length();

// now you know that the zip data begins at index and goes to the end of the byte array
// so just use a regular zipinputstream to read in the zip data.
```

Comment: I am so embarrassed that I did not think of this, works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: Although the solution is correct the faster solution would be to add some arbitral number of bytes - let's say 8 - to the end of file and store the length of JPEG there. That way you can find end of image instantly.

Answer (score 1):

In JPEG file **0xFF, 0xD8** sequence of bytes indicates start of image and **0xFF, 0xD9** sequence of bytes indicates end of image [JPEG Structure Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure). So simply search for the latter sequence in file and you will be able to separate image and zip parts. Then use `ZipInputStream` to read (decompress) the data from zip file.

Comment: It's not that simple. You would have to parse the JPEG properly to ensure you were reading records correctly, so that you only recognize 0xFFD9 when it occurs as an entire record. 0xFFD9 could occur anywhere in the middle of an image.

Comment: Yes, you're right. One would have to parse JPEG file parts properly to be 100% sure that 0xFFD9 sequence it's actually really end of image file.